# When returning a large list of Objects to ASP.Net web api it times out

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When getting data from a database and creating a list of objects from each row which comes to around 2000 objects in the list. When trying to return this list it takes enough time to time out well over 2 minutes. How can I cut this time down? filling the list takes no time at all it is only when returning it from the api call

Below is my call

```
        [HttpGet] //API GET Call
        [Route("List", Name = "Contractor List")] //API Route
        //Description
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ContractorSummary>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests)]
        public IActionResult GetContractorList(string status = "A", string locationId = "00")
        {
            //Check if API Key is valid
            if (Utilities.Helpers.IsValidApiKey(SubscriptionKey) == false)
                return Unauthorized(); //Invalid Key

            //Create an array of parameters
            var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter ("@subkey", SubscriptionKey),
                new SqlParameter ("@status", status),
                new SqlParameter ("@locationid", locationId)
            };

            //Create results DataTable and set it to GetDataTableSP sending SP name and parameters
            var results = Utilities.Data.GetDataTableSP("sp_API_GetContractor", parameters);

            var contractors = new List<ContractorSummary>();

            foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
                contractors.Add(new ContractorSummary
                {
                    Client = row["client"].ToString(),
                    ICID = row["icid"].ToString(),
                    ID2 = row["id2"].ToString(),
                    ICNUM = Convert.ToInt32(row["ICNUM"].ToString()),
                    Location = row["location"].ToString(),
                    LastName = row["LastName"].ToString(),
                    FirstName = row["firstname"].ToString(),
                    Company = row["company"].ToString(),
                    EIN = row["ein"].ToString(),
                    State = row["state"].ToString(),
                    LastPaid = DateTime.Parse(row["lastpaid"].ToString()),
                    Status = row["status"].ToString()

                    //?
                    //Self = "/contractor/detail/?icnum=" + row["ICNUM"],
                    //Profile= "/contractor/profile/?icnum=" + row["ICNUM"],
                    //Documents = "/contractor/documents/?icnum=" + row["ICNUM"]
                });
            }

            //Log Action
            Helpers.LogAction(SubscriptionKey, ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, DateTime.Now, Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString());

            return Ok(contractors);
        }
```

This is the object

```
public class ContractorSummary
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string LocationId { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public string ICID { get; set; }
        public string ID2 { get; set; }
        public int ICNUM { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string EIN { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastPaid { get; set; }

        //public string Self { get; set; }
        //public string Profile { get; set; }
        //public string Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I am getting the datatable

```
 public static DataTable GetDataTableSP(string spName, SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            //Variables
            var dsDataTable = new DataTable();
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            var conn = new SqlConnection(BuildConnectionString());

            try
            {
                // open connection
                conn.Open();

                //var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                // Create our Sql Command & give it properties
                var command = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                
                foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(p);
                }

                da.SelectCommand = command;
                da.Fill(dsDataTable);
                da.Dispose();

                // close our connection
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Dispose(); // ensure connection is closed in the event of a crash
            }

            return dsDataTable;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when testing through visual studio it was using chrome which was causing the hang up. When switching to postman it worked flawlessly.